# Casting xs:double to xs:decimal in Xpath/XSLT, custom vs built-in?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I have not dealt with sensitive number that much in the past so wanted to check.
I have input, represented as xs:double:

```
<do:amount>1.60</do:amount>
```

XSL/XPath:

```
<dec:amount><xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(do:amount)"/></dec:amount>
```

and the output should be:

```
<dec:amount>1.60</dec:amount>
```

Is there any advantage to writing a custom function that would treat do:amount as text, split by the dot character and then cast that to decimal?
Are there any scenarios that I should be careful about, where the casting or calculations may be imprecise?

Comment: If your input is XML like `<do:amount>1.60</do:amount>` and you don't use schema-aware XSLT why do you think that is an `xs:double`? It is untyped. Also I don't understand what you want to do with your custom function, can you explain in more detail whether you want it to return an atomic value like a number or an element containing the representation of a number?

Comment: Why do you ask the question? What kind of advantage are you looking for? And why do you even want to cast it to xs:decimal anyway, if all you are going to do with it is convert it back to a string? With the code as written, the output should be "1.6" rather than "1.60" because a trailing zero in a decimal is not significant.

Comment: I am asking whether I should convert to string as an interim stage of converting to decimal. The input is xs:double, the target output is xs:decimal, both declared as such in their respective schemas. Are there any cases where casting double using xs:decimal will produce an imprecise result?

Comment: I am also asking as with a custom function, I could specify a number of significant decimal places. I can do it in a number of other ways, but hacing it as part of the function (as a a param) would mean one function call and no extra code each time.

Comment: The "approximation" that leads to having lots of unwanted digits is done when you convert the string "1.60" to xs:double; the conversion of the double to xs:decimal is exact, at least in a processor like Saxon that supports infinite-precision xs:decimal. If you want the output to have a civillzed number of decimal places, you can round it either using format-number(), or using a function such as round() or round-half-to-even().

Comment: Thank you Michael. Wouldn't it make sense for me not to treat the input "1.60" as xs:double in the first place but as string instead and write a custom function to cast to decimal?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that casting `xs:double`s to `xs:decimal` can easily lead to numbers with lots of digits after the floating point, for instance when I evaluate

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" default-validation="lax">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:import-schema>
  <xs:schema>
    <xs:element name="double-amount" type="xs:double"/>
    <xs:element name="dec-amount" type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:schema>
</xsl:import-schema>

<xsl:template match="/" name="main">
  <xsl:variable name="doubles" as="element(double-amount)*">
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 10">
      <double-amount>
        <xsl:value-of select="1E0 + 1E-1 * ."/>
      </double-amount>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$doubles"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$doubles"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$doubles" mode="cast"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="double-amount">
  <dec-amount>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </dec-amount>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="double-amount" mode="cast">
  <dec-amount>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(.)"/>
  </dec-amount>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with Saxon 9.6 EE or with Saxon 9.5 EE (see http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJj) then the result is

```
<double-amount>1.1</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.2</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.3</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.4</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.5</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.6</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.7000000000000002</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.8</double-amount>
<double-amount>1.9</double-amount>
<double-amount>2</double-amount>
<dec-amount>1.1</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.2</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.3</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.4</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.5</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.6</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.7000000000000002</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.8</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.9</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>2</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.5</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>1.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375</dec-amount>
<dec-amount>2</dec-amount>
```

which shows that doing `xs:decimal(.)` instead of simply `.` in the `xsl:value-of` leads to numbers with lots of digits after the floating point which might be a precise `xs:decimal` representation of the original `xs:double` but are probably not the value you want to store. So I wonder whether you gain anything by doing `xs:decimal(.)` instead of simply copying the value through.

Comment: Exactly this - I don't have XMLSpy handy but my colleagues tell the result is exactly the opposite with XMLSpy engine - it outputs the longs numbers w/o cast and is ok w xs:decimal. SO I am trying to get to the bottom of the issue. In the end we want correct behaviour with Saxon 9.5, but I'd really rather avoid such inconsistencies.

Comment: It's not the casting of xs:double to xs:decimal that generates the unwanted decimal digits, it's the original casting of an xs:string such as "1.60" to xs:double. If you want to avoid it, the best way is to cast the string to xs:decimal without going via xs:double; alternatively you can round off the unwanted digits later.